# IIS Web Log Analyser

Tags: iis, log-files

Can anyone recommend a good IIS web log annalyzer that will serve reports/results to the web for customers.

Or maybe a good one that will export reports in a tidy format.

Thanks

Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used [WebLog Expert 6.0](http://www.weblogexpert.com/) and have liked it.  It has a nice scheduling tool and can email reports.

Answer (score 1):

AWstats will do the job.  It'll parse the access logs IIS writes.

Comment: cool thanks. Looks like I have a long few hours ahead of me. In the meantime do you know any good desktop applications that export reports in a tidy format?

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I like [Webalizer](http://www.mrunix.net/webalizer).